# Make string bold in paragraph between two delimiters javascript JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

From DB, we are getting string in following format.

```
_This is string from DB_. Make sure this is format from DB
```

Now, on JSX/javascript, I want to make string between two underscores as bold (This is string from DB to be bold format)

Comment: Is the string in the markdown format? If so, you can use libraries like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx

Comment: What have you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the string between two underscores, and wrap it with a  tag. You can use the replace method of the string object to perform this operation. For example, you can modify your code like this:

```
const dbString = "_This is string from DB_. Make sure this is format from DB";
const formattedString = dbString.replace(/_(.*?)_/g, "<b>$1</b>");
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formattedString }} />;
```